# Substring xsl hithighlightedsummary in SharePoint

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2010

I have in hithighlightedsummary  the tag this

```
<ddd /> Posted: 2/8/2011 10:04 PM <ddd /> Subject: some subject <ddd /> Some Text  <ddd />
```

I would like to get the 'some subject' as a sub string. I have tried using "substring-after(hithighlightedsummary, 'Subject:')", But I don't know how to combine that with the `<ddd />` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean something like this?

```
substring-after(
   //hithighlightedsummary
      /text()[
         contains(.,'Subject:')
      ],
   'Subject:'
)
```

**Note**: I've used an **absolute expression** because you didn't provide information about context.